# getting error while starting sonar using startsonar.bat on AWS ec2 machine

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I am new to SonarQube and I am getting following error while starting sonar using startsonar.bat on AWS ec2 windows machine 64 bit

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-5.6.7\sonarqube-5.6.7\bin\windows-x86-64>StartSonar.bat
wrapper  | --> Wrapper Started as Console
wrapper  | Launching a JVM...
jvm 1    | Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
jvm 1    |   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
jvm 1    |
jvm 1    | 2017.10.31 08:03:44 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-5.6.7\sonarqube-5.6.7\temp
jvm 1    | 2017.10.31 08:03:44 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\bin\java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-5.6.7\sonarqube-5.6.7\temp -javaagent:C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib\management-agent.jar -cp ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\sonarqube-5.6.7\sonarqube-5.6.7\temp\sq-process521585216780009921properties
wrapper  | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

I have downloaded SonarQube 5.6.7 and then unzipped it and then browsed to bin directory and executing startsonar.bat.

Comment: See what you can find in the log files: _$SONARQUBE_HOME/logs_

Comment: Did you unblock your zip-file before unzipping it?

Comment: Thank youu so much!!!i checked the logs and found that elasticsearch was using port 9001 which was already in use and the i used different port and it started successfully.